# Off smell in my mead

Tags: mead, brewing, tubing, spoilage

I recently started brewing mead and during my first racking I noticed a chemically smell that had a alcohol vinyl smell. I can't figure out if my mead has turned or not. I did another racking today and it still had that same smell... I've replaced my tube (with a new vinyl tube) and I smelled my new tube and it had the same smell before I've even used it... long story short if my mead ruined or how do I remove the chemically vinyl smell?

Comment: Take a look at this, it is probably a similar problem: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/16414/cider-smells-like-nail-polish-remover-acetone-tastes-like-juice-but-also-lik

Comment: I use acrylic tubing

Comment: What yeast strain did you use, what were your fermentation temperatures,   and did you add proper nutrition?

Answer (score 3):

If you picked up vinyl smell from fresh tubing it won't leave the mead.  It may fade in time, but along with some of the other good smells in the mead too, because it will take a long time.  And in a closed container that aroma isn't going anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a chance the plastic taste is coming from Chloroamine in the water. If you didn't treat your water with campden tables, usually 1 tablet/100l, then in futrue you should do so to avoid chemically/plastic/band-aid flavours caused byt he chlorine reating with ploy-phenols.